why is there the need of transaction token from server for the client to start the transaction?
i was using razorpay paymment gateway and the process of doing payment is first application server sends request to razorpay server for order id which is then sent to client. after that client makes another request to razorpay server using that orderid we got before and starts the transaction.
can you tell me why client just not directly sends request to razorpay server without that orderid and it should start the payment process.(note: transaction token is there in place of orderid in case of paytm)

Because of the maxim "never trust the client"

I'm sure there is some kind of authorization involved, e.g. the application server has some API token that the client shouldn't have ?

@kca what is the need of token from application server when we can directly do it from client?

If the end user would know a secret token, the user could always access the API forever (unless the token is changed). Also the user could give that token to someone else, who that could also access the API. Instead, the end user receives only a temporary token, which can be rejected at any time.
